# will tcp checksum mechanism work correctly all the time?

Tags: tcp, checksum

I am wondering if the TCP checksum mechanism could ensure the TCP data is the same as original, is there any conditions that the checksum won't work? I didn't find any reference about that.

I have an example to make my opinion clear.

The original TCP data is `11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000 ......` and it is changed to `011111111 11111111 10000000 00000000 ......` when travelling on the physical layer.

The end side will have the same checksum and it will accept the TCP data which is wrong.

I am pretty new to networking.

Comment: You are correct. A checksum cannot detect all possible errors. However it is statistically very unlikely. For example I've been downloading Java JDKs for 17 years and I've never yet had a corrupt one, and those have always been large downloads, tens of megabytes, and I've probably done it 100 times or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is always a very small chance that data corruption will preserve the checksum or will also corrupt the checksum so that the corrupted checksum matches the corrupted data. Applications that require a higher level of assurance than TCP provides have to add their own protection.

Of course, this provides no protection whatsoever from a malicious adversary. They can trivially adjust both the data and the checksum if they can intercept and modify the packets.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you, I think most banks should have a solution on higher level to protect the data.

Answer (score 1):

More details in the article here: http://criticalindirection.com/2016/02/22/tcp-checksum-the-fault-in-the-stars/

Some excerpts from the link:

```
Following are the scenarios when the data gets corrupted while the checksum stays correct [2].

Reordering of 2 byte words:
Data:      0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04
Corrupted: 0x03 0x04 0x01 0x02

Inserting zero-valued bytes:
Data:      0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04
Corrupted: 0x01 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x03 0x04

Deleting zero-valued bytes:
Data:      0x01 0x02 0x00 00 0x03 0x04
Corrupted: 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04

Replacing a string of sixteen 0’s with 1’s or 1’s with 0’s:
Data:      0xff 0xff 0xe9 0x1a 0x00 0x00 0x21
Corrupted: 0x00 0x00 0xe9 0x1a 0xff 0xff 0x21

Multiple errors which sum to zero:
Data:      0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04
Corrupted: 0x01 0x03 0x03 0x03
```

> according to Stone J. et. al. [1], 1 in 16 million to 10 billion
>   packets go unchecked as false-positive through the TCP checksum. This
>   means, for the 1500 MTU data frame on the network, 1 undetected TCP
>   corruption happens in 20GB to 1.2TB data, approximately.